# ¿Cómo eliminar una fila de una columna, dándole un parámetro en R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Quiero eliminar de una fila, de una columna, sin embargo, pero no se como decirle que borre una fila en especifico.

Ejemplo

tengo la siguiente tabla

```
  dominio

1 CIUDAD
2 RURAL
3 RESTO URBANO
```

Quiero eliminar RURAL y RESTO URBANO, ¿Cómo podría dar ese parámetro en código de R, para eliminar esos dos filas?

Comment: `df[!df$dominio %in% c('RURAL', 'RESTO URBANO'), ]`

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es usar la función [filter](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/filter) del paquete diplyr

```
library(dplyr)
dominio <- dominio %>%
    filter(dominio!= "RURAL" & dominio!= "RESTO URBANO")
```